# Passing HeaderInformation as JSONObject in Header in Spring-XD

Tags: spring, spring-integration, spring-xd

I am Passing data as JSONObject as String in Header and in next module/processor using below code but data on next module i received as "java.io.DataInputStream@7c6a857" and not able to convert it back to JSONObject as String.

```
messageOut = MessageBuilder.withPayload(message-payload).copyHeaders(payload.getHeaders()).setHeader("ActualRecord", JSONObject).build();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you are using RabbitMQ as the transport.

The `DefaultMessagePropertiesConverter` used within the bus limits headers to 1024 bytes by default; anything larger is left as a `DataInputStream` in the headers. The `MessagePropertiesConverter` is configurable for this size, but XD does not currently expose a setting to allow this to be increased.

You need to read from the DataInputStream into a `byte[]` to restore the JSON.

I have opened a [JIRA Issue](https://jira.spring.io/browse/XD-3716) to support configuration of the `LongString` limit.

Comment: Thanks for response , Yes i am using RabbitMQ and by moving it to byte[] able to re-store JSON.